# take on height on element to be replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm replacing elements that match a class with `.replaceWith()` as used here: `$('.dataCard').not('.focused').replaceWith('<div class="spaceHolder"></div>');`;however, I want each of the `.spaceHolder`s to take on the heights of the `.dataCard`s they replace before they replace them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.dataCard').not('.focused').each(function() {
    var div = $('<div />', {
        css : {height : $(this).height()}
    });
    $(this).replaceWith(div);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, nicely. I'm now trying to animate it to height: 0 and then remove it. Do you have any idea why this is not working? https://gist.github.com/theirf/36be37c84336c720a6d3